# If someone gets "too much" attention, does it expose his/her to mental illness?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality-disorder

Some psychologist told this on TV few years ago and this came to my mind when I spoke with my friend about personalities of some celebrities.

I tried to find some articles or studies about the topic on internet, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Probably it is not the attention per se, but rather the consistent high stress, negative feedback (it is news if you mess things up), etc. So, I would argue that _yes_ but only indirectly.

Comment: @just_guessing -- I believe the specific term would be *performance anxiety*, which is naturally stressful.